# SQL Server 2008 rendering nested XML

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to store a string which is already an xml, as an attribute of a root node of another xml?

The string that I want to store is `@inputXmlString`. It's value is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OneViewReviewRq
    xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<LOAN>ASFDK</LOAN>
</OneViewReviewRq>
```

I have to store this value as an attribute to another node say `row`, which is the root node. This is what the desired output should be:

```
<root oneViewXml="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OneViewReviewRq
    xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<LOAN>ASFDK</LOAN>
</OneViewReviewRq>" />
```

The problem is: when I use `for xml path` or `for xml raw` the quotes and `<` , `>` characters are not rendered as is but as `&lt;` and `&gt;` etc.

This is the query I am using:

```
select @OutputXml=(select @inputXmlString as '@oneViewXml'
for xml path('root'))
```

This is the output:

```
<root oneViewXml="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;OneViewReviewRq&#xD;&#xA;    xmlns:xsi = &quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot;&#xD;&#xA;    xmlns:xsd = &quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&quot;&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;LOAN&gt;ASFDK&lt;/LOAN&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/OneViewReviewRq&gt;" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is exactly as it should be because `<>&` are invalid characters in XML attributes. When you query your XML for the attribute value you will get the XML back as it was.

Try this:

```
declare @inputXmlString nvarchar(max) = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OneViewReviewRq
    xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<LOAN>ASFDK</LOAN>
</OneViewReviewRq>'

declare @OutputXml xml

select @OutputXml=(select @inputXmlString as '@oneViewXml'
for xml path('root'))

select @OutputXml.value('root[1]/@oneViewXml', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/123198/